# Java regex for removing all single letters except "a" and "i" from string

Tags: java, regex

I have a text string like

```
"there i r u w want to y z go because f g of a matter"
```

I want to remove all single letters except "a" and "i".
so above given example string be like

"`there i want to go because of a matter`"

What will be the java regex for removing all these single letters except "a" and "i"?

Comment: This `\b[b-hj-z] ` or ` [b-hj-z](?= )`?

Comment: i have no idea, i want regex for replaceall

Comment: I downvoted because, "gimme teh codez" / "do my work for me."

Answer (score 2):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/aXUUza/1)

```
(?:^| )[b-hj-z](?= |$)
```

#### Usage

[See code in use here](https://ideone.com/CjJqHQ)

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        final String regex = "(?:^| )[b-hj-z](?= |$)";
        final String string = "there i r u w want to y z go because f g of a matter";
        final String subst = "";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        // The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
        final String result = matcher.replaceAll(subst);

        System.out.println("Substitution result: " + result);
    }
}
```

If you need case-insensitive matching you pass `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE` to `Patter.compile`.

---

### Results

#### Input

```
there i r u w want to y z go because f g of a matter
```

#### Output

```
there i want to go because of a matter
```

---

### Explanation

- `(?:^| )` Assert position at the start of the line or match a space literally
- `[b-hj-z]` Match any lowercase ASCII letter except `a` or `i`
- `(?= |$)` Positive lookahead ensuring what follows is a space or the end of the line

Comment: wow, yes it works, thanks you very much :)

Comment: @zoric99 you can accept it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Working sample code to remove all single letters except "a" and "i"

```
String resultStr = "there i r u w want to y z go because f g of a matter".replaceAll("(?:^| )[b-hj-z | B-HJ-Z](?= |$)", "");
```

Explanation:

[image]